# Can someone help me to fix this warning: Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'ReusableView'? I search everywhere and I found nothing helpful

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone help me to fix this warning?

> Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'ReusableView'

I searched everywhere and I found nothing helpful.

```
import UIKit

extension UICollectionView {

    func register<T: UICollectionViewCell>(_: T.Type) where T: ReusableView, T: NibLoadableView {
        //warning: Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'ReusableView'

        let nib = UINib(nibName: T.nibName, bundle: nil)
        register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func dequeueReusableCell<T: UICollectionViewCell>(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> T where T: ReusableView {
        //warning: Redundant conformance constraint 'T': 'ReusableView'

        guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(T.reuseIdentifier)")
        }
        return cell
    }
}

extension UICollectionViewCell: ReusableView {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the compilator warns that the constraint is redundant. It's not an error. You can leave it as it is.

**How to fix the warning?**

Your UICollectionViewCell has already been extended somewhere in the code to conform to `ReusableView` protocol.

That's why you do not have to apply this constrain one more time.

```
func register<T: UICollectionViewCell>(_: T.Type) where T: NibLoadableView {
}
```

**Does it have an impact on the behaviour of my application?**

This has no impact on a behaviour of your application because the removed constrain was `redundant` as stated in the warning.